# Create pipe separated string

Tags: java

I am trying to create pipe separated string by in following way.

```
strBuf.append(str[0]);
strBuf.append("\\|");
```

The result is:

```
ABC\ DEF\ GHI
```

The expected result was:

```
ABC|DEF|GHI
```

What exactly I am doing wrong even after escaping it by double slash.

Comment: Why do you need to escape `|`? What is `str[0]`?

Comment: str[0] is any string.

Comment: Then you are inconsistent. Show the exact code that produces the output you posted, not "any string".

Comment: `append("\\|")` will append a \ and a |, which means it would produce `ABC\|DEF\|GHI`, not the output with spaces that you've shown.

Comment: Where is the exact code ?

Comment: If the pipe character is displayed as a space, then that happens elsewhere. The `append` call *will* insert a pipe character into the string, even without the backslashes. The double backslash is why you get backslash in your output too.

Comment: I got your point.Does java version makes any difference in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use espace sequence here. Simple do:

```
strBuf.append("|");
```

Eg:

```
String abc = "ABC";
String def = "DEF";
String ghi = "GHI";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(abc);
sb.append("|");
sb.append(def);
sb.append("|");
sb.append(ghi);
System.out.println(sb.toString()); //prints ABC|DEF|GHI
```

Comment: I was using StringBuffer,will it make any difference?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf No, but unless you need it to be thread safe, use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not escaping the `|` character?

```
strBuf.append(str[0]);
strBuf.append("|");
```

Comment: It gives output as `ABC DEF GHI`,when used with StringBuffer

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf If the pipe character is converted/displayed as a space, then that happens elsewhere. The `append("|")` *will* insert a pipe character into the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 :

```
String[] s={"ABC","DEF","GHI"};
System.out.println(String.join("|",s));
```

For JAVA 7

```
String abc = "ABC";
        String def = "DEF";
        String ghi = "GHI";
        StringBuilder strBuf=new StringBuilder();
        strBuf.append(abc);
        strBuf.append("|");
        strBuf.append(def);
        strBuf.append("|");
        strBuf.append(ghi);
        System.out.println(strBuf.toString());
```